# Linking sfDoctrineGuardPlugin with my own model schema

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, symfony-plugins

Im developing kind of a plugin for an already working system, and i intend to use symfony. My plugin requires authentication, and i want to use the symfony `sfDoctrineGuardPlugin`. I generated the schema.yaml from the existing database, using the command: `$ php symfony doctrine:build-schema`, where i had already modeled my user table, with some fields i needed, and foreign keys to other tables.

When i installed the mentioned plugin, i realized it creates its own schema, separated from mine. Is there any way to add fields to `sfDoctrineGuardPlugin`'s user table? can i make foreign keys in this table? can i reference this table from other tables? I need a way to fully customize the user table and class created by the plugin...

Thank you very much for your attention and help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The materials you got from LuisClemente are enough.

To add references you use usual way to do it.

schema.yml:

```
  sfGuardUser:
    columns:
      personal_info_id: { type: integer(5), notnull: false }    
    relations:
      PersonalInfo:
        class: PPersonalInfo
        local: personal_info_id
        foreign: id
        onDelete: CASCADE

  PPersonalInfo:
    columns:
      last_name:          { type: string(127), notnull: false }
      first_name:       { type: string(127), notnull: false }
```

For more info see [symfony blog](http://symfony.com/blog/call-the-expert-customizing-sfdoctrineguardplugin)

Comment: When i installed the plugin, it didn't put its schema in my schema.yml file... where is the plugin schema placed? can i add relations to objects not present in the same schema file? or should i merge both files???

Comment: You should not (=read must not) edit any files of plugin. Just enable plugin and add code above to your schema.yml of your project. Framework takes care to merge schema configurations.

Comment: so, if i want to add a column to the `sf_guard_user` i have to put it in my schema? like `SfGuardUser: {columns: {field1: type1, ... , fieldN: typeN } }` ? and the framework will merge my definition of the object with the definition of the plugin?  thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Exactly! One rule: try to avoid to change a vendor files (plugins, libs etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you:

[sfGuardPlugin documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfGuardPlugin)

[Adding to the sfDoctrineGuardPlugin](http://www.pressreload.com/adding-sfdoctrineguardplugin)

Search "Customize the sfGuardUser model" inside the first document. I don't know if I understand your question but I followed such documentation to add fields to my guardUser (I use Propel)

Regards

Comment: thanks! but it seems doctrine plugin doesnt have that option, or at least is not in [its documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin?tab=plugin_readme)... I dont want just to add fields, i need also to add references (foreign keys) from and to the user table.

Comment: Well, you should be able to do something similar with Doctrine inside your schema.yml (check my updated answer). In my experience it's better to add fields and functionality on a different table/model instead of changing an existing plugin. Why do you need to add references from the user table?

Comment: i need my stuff to integrate with an existing system, which classifies users according to some rules, and the way it is done, it has references to other tables so it can establish this classification. thanks for your help and interest!

Comment: @Throoze Then you can do it the way I told you for sure. Just use the plugin for login and registration porpouses and add all the logic inside your new table (and model). [Here](https://github.com/voota/voota/tree/master/www/apps/frontend/modules/sfGuardAuth) you can see a good example about SfGuardAuth Logic customization